# REST-API with generic type

Tags: c#, rest

I want to integrate a view in our client where the admins of our product can execute SQL-Statements against our Database. So I thought about a REST-API on the Server which I can call from the client and the access to this API is limited to the admin-users. This is done very easily.

The point where I struggle is the design of the GET, because when I execute a SQL-Statement the result is always different.

For example if I have the following SQL:

```
select * from view.users
```

this returns a table with the columns id, username, department and some more infos

But I also can make something like:

```
select * from view.users u
join view.components c on u.id = c.responsible
```

With this SQL I get a lot more columns.

How can I build this in a REST-API-Get and consume it?

Comment: Step 1 would be to find out what data you actually *need* on the client. Do you want column headings? Do you need the column types? Do you need the raw field values or do you need them formatted as strings? If you want everything, there are multiple hits on StackOverflow on how to serialize/deserialize a `DataTable` as JSON, for example.

Comment: You can have nullable elements within the returned data type that are not present within the data, but for simplicity of testing, I would stick with simple, rigid types and have one GET per data type, thus two calls for your example e.g., `users/GET` & `user_components/GET`